# get image url ckfinder

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I want to take the image address and add it to data-original="image url"

```
Sample : <img src="Bengal-kedisi.jpg" data-original="Bengal-kedisi.jpg"  class="lazy w-100 ortalaimg">
```

```
  on: {
    instanceReady: function() {
      this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
        elements: {
          img: function( el ) {
            if ( !el.attributes["data-original"])
              el.attributes["data-original"]= 'images URL';
            el.addClass( 'lazy w-100 ortalaimg' );

          }
        }
      } );
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you find the answer?   cause i find using ckeditor very very very difficult.

Comment: I couldnt find it. I added values like class but I couldn't get the url somehow